# If MVV application is approved by IND, can local embassy refuse for some reason?

Tags: working-visas, netherlands, europe

I am a non-EU citizen from Bangladesh. I recently got a job offer from the Netherlands as a highly skilled migrant. I never completed my Bachelor's degree, but in the Netherlands, as it's not a requirement for highly skilled migrant MVVs, the MVV application submitted by my employer might get approved.

After that, I am supposed to collect the MVV sticker from my local embassy. Are there any possibilities that my local Dutch embassy won't give me the sticker because I don't have a degree?

Edit:
The problem is not Dutch people. In fact, I have found them very nice and cooperative. Actually, the people of my country who works as consuls in the local embassy, they are the problems. They are not cooperative even to us and do not want to help in any way. They try their best to let others know about their power by denying others of any help.

Comment: If you know for sure that *it's not a requirement for highly skilled migrant MVVs*, and if your MVV sticker will a waiting for you at the local Dutch embassy, what makes you think that they won't give it to you? It's a Dutch embassy after all, not from a corrupt regime in FarAwayLand.

Comment: Hello @JanDoggen, well the problem is not Dutch people. In fact, I have found them very nice and cooperative. Actually, the people of my country who works as consuls in the local embassy, they are the problems. They are not cooperative even to us and do not want to help in any way. They try their best to let others know about their power by denying them of any help. :(

Comment: That should be in your question. Also, if you're not even mentioning which country (don't forget the tag) and which city, it's going to be impossible to answer this.

Comment: @user6083264 I would point out that the local consular staff are not consuls, nor are they officers of the Dutch government; they are just employees.  I don't know specifically about how it works in Dutch consulates, but in most countries, administrative employees do not have the power to make official decisions about matters of law or fact such as a visa application; those must be made by an officer of the government, who must normally have the nationality of the country.

Comment: Sir @JanDoggen, I am unfortunately from one of the worst parts of non-EU, Bangladesh. :(

Comment: That should *also* be in your question. Please [edit] it.

Answer (score 4):

Caveat: I'm answering on the basis of common sense and general life experience, not specific knowledge.

The IND is the relevant body which approves your request of an MVV, not the embassy. So, if the request is approved - it's an IND decision, and the embassy certainly can't overrule it, certainly not on grounds such as "MVV recipient doesn't have a Master's degree". In fact, the embassy would absolutely not even *try* to do anything like that - they have no motivation to second-guess the IND's work. Why would they care whether you have a degree or not? It's not their problem.

However, if the embassy has reason to suspect you might pose some kind of risk; if you had a violent altercation with them; if they suspect you have misrepresented information etc. - in those case it is theoretically possible that they would withhold the sticker from you. And this is regardless of whether they have the official authority to do so.

**Edit:** If you find the local consular staff uncooperative, you can try either *writing* the embassy/a consul/the ambassador, or perhaps asking for an appointment to see a consul or the ambassador. Still, I find it unlikely that local staff would be allowed to withhold documents from applicants; perhaps they're just unfriendly?

Comment: As you can see from the OP's comment 9 minutes ago, you have wasted your time (the answer is not applicable).

Comment: @JanDoggen: Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: In general, consular staff would normally have the task of evaluating local qualifications, with the in-country immigration office normally deferring to the consulate.  If there's no degree to be evaluated, that doesn't matter, of course.  The consulate is probably also responsible for clearing the application on other grounds where it is better situated than the in-country immigration office to evaluate those grounds.  A prominent example of this is criminal history.

Comment: @phoog: But this responsibility would be relevant _prior_to the IND granting an MVV. Now they just need to give OP his sticker...

Comment: @einpoklum yes, once a final decision has been made.  I was assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that we were considering a phase in the application after the IND has made whatever approvals it needs to make but before the consulate has done its own investigations.

Comment: @JanDoggen I don't see why the answer is not applicable.

Comment: @MartinBonner Now it is. Please read the edit history from both question and answer before commenting.